# Strange behavior RewriteCond on Apache 2.2

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

working .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^thumbs/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

All 404 queries to /thumbs/ folder not must be catched by /index.php script. Why top .htaccess config work and bottom config not work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thumbs/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Apache 2.2.9, Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*REQUEST_URI* contains the requested URI path and does always start with a slash.

So the pattern `^thumbs/(.*)$` does never match as it’s missing the leading `/`. But the other condition, `!^/thumbs/(.*)$`, should match every request that’s URI path does not start with `/thumbs/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the first slash in

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thumbs/(.*)$
```